# Elasticsearch - Adding node without replication?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a master/data Elasticsearch node. It has now reached 90% capacity and I need to provision additional space to continue adding more data.

I have created a new server with 700gb disk space, installed ES & Kibana, and now wish for this second server to provide additional space to / work with the master node.

**My problem:**

As it says on the [ES website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html):

> When you add more nodes to a cluster, it automatically allocates
>   replica shards.

My issue is that I do not wish to replicate the data from the master node, but instead just provide additional space using this second server which can then be queried by the master node.

**My question:**

What is the best way to achieve this? Is adding a node the incorrect thing to do here?

Comment: A master node doesn't hold any data, its only job is to baby-sit the cluster, but there's no data on it. I guess your single node is a master/data node, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Do you have replica shards or only primary? If the latter, then your cluster must currently be yellow, otherwise it is green, correct?

Comment: Only primary - they are yellow

Comment: So if you have only primary shards and your cluster is yellow, it means you also have unassigned shards, is that right?

Comment: Yes, using `GET /_cat/shards?h=index,shard,prirep,state,unassigned.reason|` I can see they are all `STARTED` / `UNASSIGNED`. To provide context, this is currently a single server instance with a fresh install of ES that I have created indexes on and populated with data. No additional scaling/architecture adjustment has taken place

Comment: ok the UNASSIGNED ones is what causes your cluster to be yellow instead of green. Any reason why they are unassigned? Back to your initial question, I don't get why you don't want your data to get spread over both nodes, you'd have the same amount of free space anyway, just not only on the second node, but a bit on both. What's the problem with that?

Comment: They're unassigned because I'm quite new to ES and haven't explored optimizing/assigning yet. I don't want my data to spread because I don't want the new 700gb server I've provisioned to be filled up with data from the other node - it has limited space and should just be for the new data I wish to import. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What are the names of your current indexes?

Comment: orders, orders_1, orders_2, orders_3, orders_4, orders_5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198949/discussion-between-john-cliven-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [index-level shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html), you can constrain a given index (or set of indexes) to stay on a given node (or set of nodes).

Simply run this:

```
PUT orders,orders_1,orders_2,orders_3,orders_4,orders_5/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "your-first-node-name"
}
```

Note that you can also use `._ip` or `._host` instead of `._name` if you prefer.

Then you can add a new node and let it join the cluster and nothing will rebalance, all your current shards will stay on your current node.

And if you need to create a new index on the second node and want to make sure that it will stay on that node you can specify the same settings at index creation time:

```
PUT new_orders
{
  "settings": {
      "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "your-second-node-name"
  }
}
```

The index called `new_orders` will be created on the second node and stay there.

Comment: This seems perfect, thank you for your help. If I want to add new data to a new index, how do I specify that it should allocate on the new node and not the older, close to capacity master node?